# Trying to find mass of volume: apparently my bounds are incorrect but I don't see why

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

[image]

This is what I got: $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x}  \,4dzdydx$

Looking at the domain D on the xy plane, the lower bound for x is 0, as given, and I set z = 0 in x + z = 1 to get x = 1 as the upper bound. Then I set z = 0 in z = 1-y^2 to get y = -1 and 1; these are y's bounds. Finally, we know z = 0 as the lower bound and the upper bound is x + z = 1 => z = 1-x. Apparently my answer is wrong: can someone explain?

Comment: It's wrong because $z$ has two upper bounds. If you were to do $dz$ first this should be two integrals (or more, depending on how the plane cuts across the cylinder). The order I recommend is $dxdzdy$, but $dxdydz$ would also be one integral.

Comment: @NinadMunshi For dxdzdy, what is Z's upper bound? I know y's bounds are -1,1 and Z's lower bound is 0, but is its upper bound 1-x or 1-y^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $(x,y,z)$ in that region, $x$ can take any value from $0$ to $1$ and $z$ can take any value from $0$ to $1-x$. Finally, $y$ can take any value from $-\sqrt{1-z}$ to $\sqrt{1-z}$. So, compute$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_{-\sqrt{1-z}}^{\sqrt{1-z}}4\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have two questions: Why do you set Z's upper bound to 1 - x as opposed to $1 - y^2$? And why are y's bounds in terms of Z as opposed to -1 and 1?

Comment: It's because each inner integral is defined in terms of its outer integral, right?

Comment: @beginner You are right: it's because each inner integral must depend upon those that have appeared before.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up as below -

$\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_{-\sqrt{1-z}}^{\sqrt{1-z}} 4 \, dy\, dz \, dx$

or

$\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-z}}^{\sqrt{1-z}}\int_{0}^{1-z} 4 \, dx \, dy \, dz$

The problem in setting it up wrt $dz$ first the way you did is that the upper bound of $z$ is the plane and that will not give the correct bound for $y$.